# exit status 1 expected primary-expression before 'int'

Tags: programming, code-review

```
int temp=A0;
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SSID "rab"
#define PASSWORD "rakesh1234"
#define IP "184.106.153.149" // thingspeak.com
String GET = "GET /update?key=B8B8E4FC1K541QZQ&field1=";
SoftwareSerial monitor(0, 1); // RX, TX
SoftwareSerial mySerial(5, 6); // RX, TX
int p1=0,p2=0,p3=0;
int i=0;
int j=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(A0,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  monitor.begin(115200);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  sendDebug("AT");
  delay(2000);
  if(Serial.find("OK")) {
    monitor.println("RECEIVED: OK");
    Serial.println("RECEIVED: OK");
  }
  connectWiFi();
}

unsigned char buf[50];

void loop() {
   while(!mySerial.available());
   if(mySerial.read() == '#') {
     for(int i=0;i<12;i++) {
       while(!mySerial.available());
       buf[i] = mySerial.read();
     }
     buf[3] =0;
     buf[7]=0;
     buf[11]=0;
     p1 = atoi((const char *)&buf[0]);
     p2 = atoi((const char *)&buf[4]);
     p3 = atoi((const char *)&buf[8]);
     delay(1000);
   }

   long int SensorValue=analogRead(temp);
   SensorValue=SensorValue*5000;
   SensorValue=SensorValue/1024;
   SensorValue=SensorValue/10;
   SensorValue=SensorValue*9;
   SensorValue=SensorValue/5;
   SensorValue=SensorValue+32;
   String tempF=String(p1);
   String tempFF=String(p2);
   String tempFFF=String(p3);
   String tempFFFF=String(SensorValue);

   for(int j=0;j>-1;j++) {
     **j= Serial.read(int p1, int p2, int p3);**
   }
   while(Serial.available()==j)
     updateTemp(tempF,tempFF,tempFFF,tempFFFF);
   while(1) {}
 }

 void updateTemp(String tempF1 ,String tempF2, String tempF3,  String tempF4) {
   String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
   cmd += "api.thingspeak.com";
   cmd += "\",80";
   sendDebug(cmd);
   delay(1000);
   if(Serial.find("Error")) {
     monitor.print("RECEIVED: Error");
     Serial.print("RECEIVED: ERROR");
     return;
   }
   cmd = GET;
   cmd += tempF1;
   cmd += "&field2=";
   cmd += tempF2;
   cmd +="&field3=";
   cmd +=tempF3;
   cmd +="&field4=";
   cmd +=tempF4;
   cmd += "\r\n";
   Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
   Serial.println(cmd.length());
   if(Serial.find(">")) {
     monitor.print(">");
     monitor.print(cmd);
     Serial.print(cmd);
   } else {
     sendDebug("AT+CIPCLOSE");
   }
   if(Serial.find("OK")) {
     monitor.println("RECEIVED: OK");
   } else {
     monitor.println("RECEIVED: Error");
   }
 }

 void sendDebug(String cmd) {
   monitor.print("SEND: ");
   monitor.println(cmd);
   Serial.println(cmd);
 }

 boolean connectWiFi() {
   Serial.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
   delay(2000);
   String cmd="AT+CWJAP=\"";
   cmd+=SSID;
   cmd+="\",\"";
   cmd+=PASSWORD;
   cmd+="\"";
   sendDebug(cmd);
   delay(1000);
   if(Serial.find("OK")) {
     monitor.println("RECEIVED: OK");
     return true;
   } else {
     monitor.println("RECEIVED: Error");
     return false;
   }
 }
```

This is my code. I am getting an error as "exit status 1 
expected primary-expression before 'int'"

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please reformat your code properly so we can read it. Also, what line number does the error happen at?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing Serial.read() wrong with:

```
Serial.read(int p1, int p2, int p3);
```

`Serial.read()` takes no parameters per https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/read

Maybe you want to try `parseInt()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your are using asterisks ("*")

```
   for(int j=0;j>-1;j++) {
     **j= Serial.read(int p1, int p2, int p3);**
   }
```

The asterisk in C/C++ is the **pointer operator**. You use to get the value pointed by a pointer.

The expression `**j` means that `j` is a pointer to a pointer that points something. That's is meaningless here.

Then, the last `**` is readed as another pointer to a pointer, and the compiler is expecting a variable or expression that give the value for the pointer, but found "}", which is an error.

You probably tried to comment out that line of code after the compiler barks at the `Serial.read()`, which, as Dave X pointed out, is illegal, because `Serial.read()` takes no arguments.

And, the syntax `function(int x)` is only use for declaring a function, not for calling one.